# Adding time delay to google map geocode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm working on this map and trying to geocode around 150 markers but I'm hitting the geocode limit. How can I add a time delay to avoid hitting the limit?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide only Javascript code without PHP, especially when you wish the answer incorporated into your code.

Comment: @Jiri It can be easily found by viewing the source of the link provided. I've included it this way as other aspects were clashing with the php previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds a timer to the geocoding so each marker has a delay.

```
// Adding a LatLng object for each city 
function geocodeAddress(i) {
     geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[i]}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            places[i] = results[0].geometry.location;

            // Adding the markers 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: places[i], map: map});
            markers.push(marker);
            mc.addMarker(marker);

            // Creating the event listener. It now has access to the values of i and marker as they were during its creation
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                // Check to see if we already have an InfoWindow
                if (!infowindow) {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                }

                // Setting the content of the InfoWindow
                infowindow.setContent(popup_content[i]);

                // Tying the InfoWindow to the marker 
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            // Extending the bounds object with each LatLng 
            bounds.extend(places[i]); 

            // Adjusting the map to new bounding box 
            map.fitBounds(bounds) 
        } else { 
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); 
        }
    })
}

function geocode() {
    if (geoIndex < address.length) {
        geocodeAddress(geoIndex);
        ++geoIndex;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(geoTimer);
    }
}
var geoIndex = 0;
var geoTimer = setInterval(geocode, 200);  // 200 milliseconds (to try out)

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers); 
} 
})
(); 
</script>
```

ADDED. The above program can be tuned.

(1) The time interval can be reduced:

```
var geoTimer = setInterval(geocode, 100);  // do requests each 100 milliseconds
```

(2) The function geocode() could perform several requests at each time interval, e.g. 5 requests:

```
function geocode() {
    for (var k = 0; k < 5 && geoIndex < address.length; ++k) {
        geocodeAddress(geoIndex);
        ++geoIndex;
    }
    if (geoIndex >= address.length) {
        clearInterval(geoTimer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give this a go, I'm rubbish with Javascript so I'll probably mess it up!

Comment: Could you possibly put that into my code? Starting with the line "// Adding a LatLng object for each city" down to the closing </script> please? I just tried and messed it up, my javascript is terrible!

Comment: I edited my code such that you would copy it from "Adding a LatLng object for each city" to the end of your file. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much. Seems there's a syntax error somewhere as the link is just a blank page.

Comment: I've found the syntax error and fixed it. Is there no other way to avoid having to sit there and watching each marker plot?

Comment: Thanks. Trying to work out the tipping point of hitting the limit. Setting the delay to 1000 worked without hitting the limit. Doing 5 requests at 1000 seems to hit the limit. Obviously the faster the better.

Comment: It seems getting 1 marker per 1000 seems the tipping point, any more than that then it hits the limit.