# Geocoder Gem Switch API Key Or Different Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I currently have the `geocoder` gem install on my Rails 3 application.

I have to upload a list of about 3k - 4k locations every week several locations are the same so i don't have to look all of them up every time. But i continually get errors. More then likely the request per second. because i can try it agian and more locations will get entered but will stop after 40 - 50 more entered.

I would like to alternate between 2 - 3 Api keys or 2 - 3 services for geocoding

```
  attr_accessible :cs, :latitude, :longitude, :city, :state
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :cs_changed?

  geocoded_by :cs do |obj, results|
    geo = results.first
    if geo
      obj.latitude = geo.latitude
      obj.longitude = geo.longitude
      obj.city  = geo.city
      obj.state = geo.state_code
    end
  end
```

How can i configure Multiple services or multiple keys to work with the geocoder gem

Comment: It's not allowed:  [***you agree not to .....obtain or attempt to obtain multiple keys for the same URL***](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=de#section_10_1) (10.1.1.g.xv)

Comment: You're going to have to add a delay between requests. As long as you're under the actual query limit, a delay will enable your processing to run to completion. Here's a method for adding such a delay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659187/adding-time-delay-to-google-map-geocode